# How can I set the newPositions distance to be shorter closer to the original squadMembers positions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 3 formations:
In each formation I'm calculating new positions to move to and add them to the List newPositions.

```
private void FormationTriangle()
    {
        newpositions = new List<Vector3>();

        int height = Mathf.CeilToInt((Mathf.Sqrt(8 * squadMembers.Count + 1f) - 1f) / 2);
        int slots = (int)(height * (height + 1f) / 2f);

        float verticalModifier = 1.25f;  // * 1.25f to increase horizontal space
        float horizontalModifier = 0.8f; // * 0.8f to decrease "vertical" space

        float width = 0.5f * (height - 1f);
        Vector3 startPos = new Vector3(width * horizontalModifier, 0f, (float)(height - 1f) * verticalModifier);

        int finalRowCount = height - slots + squadMembers.Count;
        for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < height && newpositions.Count < squadMembers.Count; rowNum++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rowNum + 1 && newpositions.Count < squadMembers.Count; i++)
            {
                float xOffset = 0f;

                if (rowNum + 1 == height)
                {
                    // If we're in the last row, stretch it ...
                    if (finalRowCount != 1)
                    {
                        // Unless there's only one item in the last row. 
                        // If that's the case, leave it centered.

                        xOffset = Mathf.Lerp(
                                rowNum / 2f,
                                -rowNum / 2f,
                                i / (finalRowCount - 1f)
                                ) * horizontalModifier;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    xOffset = (i - rowNum / 2f) * horizontalModifier;
                }

                float yOffset = (float)rowNum * verticalModifier;

                Vector3 position = new Vector3(
                        startPos.x + xOffset, 0f, startPos.y - yOffset);
                newpositions.Add(position);

            }
        }

        move = true;
        formation = Formation.Square;
    }

    private Vector3 FormationSquarePositionCalculation(int index) // call this func for all your objects
    {
        float posX = (index % columns) * gaps;
        float posY = (index / columns) * gaps;
        return new Vector3(posX, posY);
    }

    private void FormationSquare()
    {
        newpositions = new List<Vector3>();
        quaternions = new List<Quaternion>();

        for (int i = 0; i < squadMembers.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector3 pos = FormationSquarePositionCalculation(i);

            //squadMembers[i].transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + pos.x, 0, transform.position.y + pos.y);
            squadMembers[i].transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -90, 0));
            newpositions.Add(new Vector3(transform.position.x + pos.x, 0, transform.position.y + pos.y));
        }
        move = true;
        squareFormation = true;
        formation = Formation.Circle;
    }

    private Vector3 FormationCirclePositionCalculation(Vector3 center, float radius, int index, float angleIncrement)
    {
        float ang = index * angleIncrement;
        Vector3 pos;
        pos.x = center.x + radius * Mathf.Sin(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        pos.z = center.z + radius * Mathf.Cos(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        pos.y = center.y;
        return pos;
    }

    private void FormationCircle()
    {
        newpositions = new List<Vector3>();
        quaternions = new List<Quaternion>();

        Vector3 center = transform.position;
        float radius = (float)circleRadius / 2;
        float angleIncrement = 360 / (float)numberOfSquadMembers;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSquadMembers; i++)
        {
            Vector3 pos = FormationCirclePositionCalculation(center, radius, i, angleIncrement);

            var rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(center - pos);

            if (Terrain.activeTerrain == true)
                pos.y = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(pos);
            pos.y = pos.y + yOffset;
            newpositions.Add(pos);
            quaternions.Add(rot);
        }
        move = true;
        squareFormation = false;
        formation = Formation.Triangle;
    }
```

Then I'm moving the squadMembers to the newPositions:

```
private void MoveToNextFormation()
    {
        if (randomSpeed == false)
        {
            if (step.Length > 0)
                step[0] = moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < squadMembers.Count; i++)
        {
            squadMembers[i].transform.LookAt(newpositions[i]);

            if (Vector3.Distance(squadMembers[i].transform.position, newpositions[i]) > 30f)
            {
                if (randomSpeed == true)
                {
                    squadMembers[i].transform.position =
                Vector3.MoveTowards(squadMembers[i].transform.position, newpositions[i], step[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    squadMembers[i].transform.position =
                    Vector3.MoveTowards(squadMembers[i].transform.position, newpositions[i], step[0]);
                }
            }

            if (Vector3.Distance(squadMembers[i].transform.position, newpositions[i]) < threshold)
            {
                if (squareFormation == true)
                {
                    Vector3 degrees = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                    Quaternion quaternion = Quaternion.Euler(degrees);
                    squadMembers[i].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(squadMembers[i].transform.rotation, quaternion, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
                else
                {
                    squadMembers[i].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(squadMembers[i].transform.rotation, quaternions[i], rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

But if I want that the squadMembers will not move at all but will change to the next formation on the same position they are ? Or maybe to move just a little bit for example to distance 20 or 5 or 30 or 300 ?

I tried to add a distance check for the move:

```
if (Vector3.Distance(squadMembers[i].transform.position, newpositions[i]) > 30f)
```

So they are changing to the next formation when the distance more then 30.
But then the formation is not looking good. If for example it's the square formation the formation after they finished moving looks like a wave.

Screenshot example:

[Wave formation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N76j.jpg)

Comment: I am not quite sure if I got this right. But it seems that you might want to consider creating a center point. Then when you change your formation you will have to refer to the center point and not only (if not at all) to the individual points position.

Comment: @Skdy So the whole squad/s will move to that point as position instead to newPositions list.  This way I can change the center point position as distance ? But then all the squads and squadmembers will move to the same position(center point).

Comment: Not exactly. Think about it as a reference point. You need a center point and a direction. Then when a formation is changed, you can fetch a center point of the current formation and shape your new formation by knowing this point. I must say that I dont think it is that simple of a task, but it should very well be doable.